# iOS Swift: AES key+salt decryption

Tags: ios, swift, encryption, aes, jwt

I am currently trying to decrypt a JWT Token using the PBE AES Encryption, but the problem that I am facing is that the value always returns nil when i try to convert the data received after decryption. I am using CryptoSwift and CommonCrypto to do the needful. Below are the snippets of my codebase.

This is how I am trying to convert the key and salt to the respective key that can be used for decryption.

```
let keyData:NSData = PRIVATE_KEY.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!;
    let saltData:NSData = SALT_KEY.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!;

    var hashkeyData:NSMutableData = NSMutableData(length:kCCKeySizeAES256)!;

    let ptr = UnsafePointer<Int8>(keyData.bytes)
    let saltPtr = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(saltData.bytes);
    let hashKeyPtr = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(hashkeyData.mutableBytes);
    let result = CCKeyDerivationPBKDF(UInt32(kCCPBKDF2), ptr, keyData.length, saltPtr, saltData.length, UInt32(kCCPRFHmacAlgSHA256), 1000, hashKeyPtr, hashkeyData.length);

    assert(result == Int32(kCCSuccess),"Unable to create AES key for password: \(result)");

    return hashkeyData as NSData;
```

Here is the code for the decryption.

```
    let encodedData = encryptedToken.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);
        let encodedBase64Data = NSData(base64EncodedString: encryptedToken ,options: []);
        let encodedDataArray = encodedBase64Data?.arrayOfBytes();

        let stringData = NSString(data: encodedBase64Data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding);
        print("Base 64 Encoded Data: \(stringData)");

        let keyData = self.getPBEKey();
        let keyDataArray = keyData.arrayOfBytes();
        let keyVal:[UInt8] = Array(keyDataArray[0...31]);

        let ivDataArray = Array(keyDataArray[0...15]);

        let decryptedData:[UInt8]?;

        do {
            let aesObject = AES(key: keyVal, iv: ivDataArray, blockMode: .CBC);

            decryptedData = try aesObject?.decrypt(encodedDataArray!,padding: PKCS7());
            let convertedData = NSData(bytes: decryptedData!, length: decryptedData!.count);
print("Decrypted Data: \(String(data:convertedData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)))")             

        } catch {
            print("Error \(error)");
        }
```

The problem that I am currently facing is the value for the **Decrypted Data** always comes out to be nil which should be a valid JWT Token.

Has someone encountered such kind of situation earlier or else is there something that I am missing in the above code which is leading to the issue.

Comment: It is best to avoid using CryptoSwift, amoung other things it is over 500 to 1000 times slower than Common Crypto based implementations. Apple's Common Crypto is FIPS certified and as such has been well vetted, using CryptoSwift is taking a chance on correctness and security.

Comment: @zaph What do you suggest in such a case if not using  CryptoSwift. Can you please direct me towards some implementation using CommonCrypto.

Comment: Use Common Crypto for the encryption, you are already using it for CCKeyDerivationPBKDF in one place.

Comment: but it seems to be not working.. I tried it using FBEncryptor too but still value of the converted string comes out to be nil.. Seems to be something that I am doing wrong in key generation

Comment: There is no "the PBE AES Encryption." There are many ways to convert passwords into keys and many ways to use AES with that key. None of them are compatible, and any mismatch will lead to garbage. How exactly are you generating your cipher text? Have you validated that the decryption key exactly matches the encryption key? What error was thrown by decrypt?